# command for importing a keystore into a kdb file

Tags: ssl-certificate, websphere, keystore, ibmhttpserver

I was following commandline installation of CLM 6.0.5 with liberty profile (distributed environment) and I could complete the installation part of application successfully by following the ibm documents.

Also Ii have installed the IBM HTTP Server in separate server and now I need to do the SSL certificate import and handshake with the loberty profile.

The reference link which I am using here.  - https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Deployment/CLMDistributedSetupUsingLibertyProfile

part 1 -Create a key database and self-signed certificate for IHS

---

I completed these steps by below 2 Using gskcmd, command line and it was success.

On the IHS machine, Open a command terminal and cd to /bin, e.g. /opt/IBM/HTTPServer/bin, 
         Create the key database
            ./gskcmd -keydb -create -db ihskeys.kdb -pw xxxxx -expire 3650 -stash -type cms 
         Create the self-signed certificate for IHS URL
            ./gskcmd -cert -create -db ihskeys.kdb  -label default -expire 3650 -size 2048 -dn "CN=xxxxx" -default_cert yes -pw xxxxx

But in part 2-  Setup SSL Handshake between the Liberty profiles and IHS

---

I couldn't find any proper commandline guidance to do this through commands. From each application servers (JTS, CCM, QM, RM) I copied the default keystore files ([JAZZ_HOME]\server\liberty\servers\clm\resources\security\ibm-team-ssl.keystore)
to IHS server and I need to import these keystore file to IHS kdb file through command line. I tried with various option and its getting failed.

./gskcapicmd -cert -import -db /opt/IBM/HTTPServer/ibm-team-ssl.keystore -pw ibm-team -target /opt/IBM/HTTPServer/key.kdb -target_pw ibm-team

it's giving error as invalid keystore format. Here my aim is to import these copied keystore files to IHS kdb file in personal certificate)

Comment: Is "import" really the write operation here?  It seems like you should be doing an "extract" of the CA used to sign each liberty servers certificate then doing an "add" on the KDB.

Answer (score 1):

IHS includes two command-line certificate management tools, only the java-based "`[IHS Home]/bin/gskcmd`" (aka ikeycmd) can read or write ****.jks*** java keystores.

Comment: Hello Covener.. Thanks for your suggestion here. I am already using the same commandline tool and i couldnt get it done as i explained above. Actually i want import the keystore file from other liberty servers to IHS kdb personal certificate first. And in second step i have one more kdb file in IHS which for webserver plugin and where i want to add the other liberty servers extracted certificates in signer part of kdb file in ihs